# Can you develop a .Net Compact Framework application in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

Title explains the main question.  I have to develop a .NET CF application for a customer.  We only have a license for VS2019.  I see you can in VS2008, but it cant be licensed, so there is no way to develop in that IDE, since a license cant be purchased anymore.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a MSDN subscription, you can get every VS version you need including License IDs.

Comment: You may also use the free SharpDevelop (up to Version 3), but use with some caution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Visual Studio 2008 was the last supported VS for Compact Framework. We still have it installed and need it installing on all build servers for our release pipelines to continue development for it.

Regarding licensing, MSDN subscription usually includes all previous versions or I'm sure you could buy a key from eBay from someone cleaning out their old IT cupboards!

Answer (score 0):

To some extent yes, but probably no. It is possible to get Visual Studio 2019, later versions, or MsBuild CLI on a build server to build Compact Framework libraries.

However, if you are working on a GUI application this will not be an effective solution, because much of the other tools needed to maintain a Compact Framework such as the Designer, CAB installer builder, and tools for deploying and debugging are just in Visual Studio 2008.

[Here is a guide](https://gist.github.com/skarllot/4953ddb6e23d8a6f0816029c4155997a) on using Compact Framework with newer versions of Visual Studio, if all you need is to set up a code library.